# Why compiler in given me this cannot convert from CompletableFuture<Object> to CompletableFuture<String>

Tags: generics, java-8, completable-future

I'm trying to chain some file handling procedures using CompletableFuture, that is supposed to return a `CompletableFuture<String>`:

```
CompletableFuture<String> allGen = loadFile1().thenApply(params1 -> {

    CompletableFuture<String> gen1 = loadFile2().thenApply(params2 -> {
        return generateResultFile1(params1, params2);
    });

    CompletableFuture<String> gen2 = loadFile3().thenApply(params3 -> {
        return generateResultFile2(params1, params3);
    });

    return CompletableFuture
        .allOf(gen1, gen2)
            .thenApply(r -> Stream.of(gen1, gen2).map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(joining(",")));
});
```

I know that `CompletableFuture.allOf()` returns `CompletableFuture<Void>`, so I'm generating a string in its `thenApply()`...

But why is the compiler is assuming that I'm producing a `CompletableFuture<Object>` here ?

What am I missing here, please?

Btw, it is a better way to chain methods like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main clause is

```
CompletableFuture<String> allGen = loadFile1().thenApply(params1 -> {
    …
});
```

So the specified function is supposed to return a `String`. But your code is trying to return a `CompletableFuture<String>`, as `Stream.of(gen1, gen2) .map(CompletableFuture::join) .collect(joining(","))` produces a `String` and you’re using this expression in `return CompletableFuture .allOf(gen1, gen2) .thenApply(r -> …);`

The compiler error messages are often very unhelpful in cases of such type mismatches in generic code.

The simplest fix (with the smallest change) is to use `thenCompose` instead of `thenAppy`, allowing the function to return a `CompletableFuture`.

```java
CompletableFuture<String> allGen = loadFile1().thenCompose(params1 -> {

    CompletableFuture<String> gen1 = loadFile2().thenApply(params2 -> {
        return generateResultFile1(params1, params2);
    });

    CompletableFuture<String> gen2 = loadFile3().thenApply(params3 -> {
        return generateResultFile2(params1, params3);
    });

    return CompletableFuture.allOf(gen1, gen2)
        .thenApply(r -> Stream.of(gen1, gen2)
            .map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(joining(",")));
});
```

There are, however, opportunities to use simplified syntax

```java
CompletableFuture<String> allGen = loadFile1().thenCompose(params1 -> {
    CompletableFuture<String> gen1 = loadFile2()
        .thenApply(params2 -> generateResultFile1(params1, params2));

    CompletableFuture<String> gen2 = loadFile3()
        .thenApply(params3 -> generateResultFile2(params1, params3));

    return CompletableFuture.allOf(gen1, gen2)
        .thenApply(r -> Stream.of(gen1, gen2)
            .map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(joining(",")));
});
```

If the code is always combining exactly two results, you can use the even simpler:

```java
CompletableFuture<String> allGen = loadFile1().thenCompose(params1 ->
    loadFile2().thenApply(params2 -> generateResultFile1(params1, params2))
        .thenCombine(
            loadFile3().thenApply(params3 -> generateResultFile2(params1, params3)),
            (s1, s2) -> String.join(",", s1, s2))
);
```

Despite the different nesting, `loadFile2().thenApply(…)` and `loadFile3().thenApply(…)` are still two independent operations and only the final `(s1, s2) -> String.join(",", s1, s2)` depends on both.

If you want to make this more obvious, keep the local variables

```java
CompletableFuture<String> allGen = loadFile1().thenCompose(params1 -> {
    CompletableFuture<String> gen1
        = loadFile2().thenApply(params2 -> generateResultFile1(params1, params2));
    CompletableFuture<String> gen2
        = loadFile3().thenApply(params3 -> generateResultFile2(params1, params3));
    return gen1.thenCombine(gen2, (s1, s2) -> s1 + "," + s2);
});
```

As shown in the last example, you may also replace `String.join(",", s1, s2)` with `s1 + "," + s2` here. The latter will be slightly more efficient, but since it’s rather unlikely to dominate the overall performance, it’s rather a matter of taste.

Comment: many thanks ;)
About your last improvement: will the `gen1.thenCombine(gen2` make those gen1 and gen2 be run in parallel / concomitant?

Comment: Like with `allOf`, this has no influence on their completion at all. It’s the methods `loadFile2()` and `loadFile3()` and the way they create the futures, which determines how they will be completed. Both methods, `allOf` and `thenCombine` (and all other chained actions as well), only create a new future that will be completed when the incoming futures have been completed. If you want to be sure that `generateResultFile1` and `generateResultFile2` run in parallel in every case, you have to replace both `thenApply` with `thenApplyAsync`.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I understood now. Both generation methods have a `return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`. I'm going to add a log on them in order to see which threads are being used to execute them.